# HTTP 403 Error when extracting full links from webpages with urllib.request.urlopen(url)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download all **full** links from a list of websites. The code is as follows,

```
def get_links(url):
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)

all_links = [url]

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    out=urljoin(url, link.get('href'))
    if out not in all_links:
        all_links.append(out)
return all_links
```

It works well for the most websites, but it did not work in some sites, such as http://my.clevelandclinic.org/locations/akron-general. The Error message is "649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"

I read a lot of posts and tried to fix or bypass it. I tried to add the header, and used try/except statement, but none works. The site is accessible. When I used another code, as follows, I could download two links, but not all.

```
def get_links(url):
all_links = [url]
    
req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    out=urljoin(url, link.get('href'))
    if out not in all_links:
        all_links.append(out)
    return all_links
```

The second code cannot download all full links. Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A 403 response pretty clearly states that the requested website has implemented some kind of security against web scraping bots. Try passing a commonly used user agent. Some websites look for user-agent or for presence of specific headers before accepting the request.

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

I’d also recommend using session instead of urllib which has a higher success rate:

import requests

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('some-url', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

print(response.status_code)

…and do whatever web scraping stuff using beautiful soup

If you still get 403 on some websites, try adding more headers:

headers = {
'user-agent':"Mozilla/5.0 ...",
'accept': '"text/html,application...',
'referer': 'https://...',
}
r = session.get(url, headers=headers)

Some websites have a strong security check against scraping so all the above may not work which is understandable.

Comment: Thank you. However, it  only scrape two links as my 2nd code.